# TypeError at /image/ expected string or Unicode object, InMemoryUploadedFile found

Tags: python, django, opencv, machine-learning

I have build a image processing classifier and In this code I am making an api which takes the input image form key 'test_image' and predicts the class of the image but `cv2.imread()` is giving me this error

> TypeError at /image/ expected string or Unicode object, InMemoryUploadedFile found

I know that `cv2.imread` takes only url of the image but I don't know how to resolve this.

My code:

```
def classify_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['test_image']:
        test_image = request.FILES['test_image']
        test_image = cv2.imread(test_image)
        test_image = cv2.resize(test_image, (128, 128))
        test_image = np.array(test_image)
        test_image = test_image.astype('float32')
        test_image /= 255
        print(test_image.shape)

        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        pred = model.predict_classes(test_image)
        print(pred)

   return JsonResponse(pred, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer 
imread takes only path of the file.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `imread` method is intended to read an image from a file. There's a different method, `imdecode`, for reading the image from memory. Try replacing line 4 of your code with this:

```
test_image = cv2.imdecode(test_image.read())
```

Source:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/uploads/

Comment: it gives me this error ( TypeError: Required argument 'flags' (pos 2) not found )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295025/valueerror-at-image-tensor-tensoractivation-5-softmax0-shape-4-dtyp/47300005?noredirect=1#comment81555441_47300005 any suggesions